# Using multiple prototype cells in swift only works when one is deactivated

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've a table view that has 2 prototype cells. One with an image and another without.

When I run the app on simulator my tableview display the correct rows accordingly, if they have image or not. But these rows come with NO CONTENT. Neither text or image.

But if I comment `let standardCell` and use only `let imageCell` or vice-versa I get the rows populated, but base in the prototype that is not commented.

Here is my output and here you can see I am getting everything from the database and I am also triggering the correct cell.

```
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(false) AT INDEX PATH -> 0
STANDARD CELL AT->(0, Optional("no image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(true) AT INDEX PATH -> 1
IMAGE CELL AT->(1, Optional("image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(false) AT INDEX PATH -> 0
STANDARD CELL AT->(0, Optional("no image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(true) AT INDEX PATH -> 1
IMAGE CELL AT->(1, Optional("image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(true) AT INDEX PATH -> 2
IMAGE CELL AT->(2, Optional("image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(false) AT INDEX PATH -> 3
STANDARD CELL AT->(3, Optional("no image"))
HAS IMAGE?->Optional(true) AT INDEX PATH -> 4
IMAGE CELL AT->(4, Optional("image"))
```

**Code**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Cell identifiers
        let standardCellIdentifier = "StandardCell"
        let imageCellIdentifier = "ImageCell"

        //variables
        var imageForCell = UIImage()
        var testString = String()
//        var hasImage = true

        //cells
        let standardCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(standardCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbieFeedStandardTVCell
        let imageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbieFeedImageTVCell

        //get object, text and votes
        let object = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        var myText = object.objectForKey("postText") as? String
        println("MY TEXT -> \(myText)")
        var hasImage = object.objectForKey("hasImage") as? Bool
        let imageFromParse = object.objectForKey("postImage") as? PFFile
//        var myVotes = object.objectForKey("postVotes") as? String

        //find if there is an image
         println("HASIMAGE IS->\(indexPath.row, hasImage)")

        //get image
        if hasImage == true
        {
            println("RETURNED IMAGE->\(indexPath.row)")
            //set image for cell
            imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    if let myImageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:myImageData)
                        imageCell.cellImage!.image = image
                    }
                }
                }, progressBlock: { (percent: Int32) -> Void in
            })

//            imageCell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "logoPDF")
            imageCell.cellText.text = "has image"
            return imageCell
        }

            println("RETURNED STANDARD->\(indexPath.row)")
            standardCell.cellText.text = "no image"
            return standardCell

    }
```

Comment: Why do you dequeue both the standard cell and the image cell? First check if there is an image and then dequeue the cell you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last return statement is everytime called. add it in `if` and `else`.

And deque the cell if you want it at one time.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Cell identifiers
        let standardCellIdentifier = "StandardCell"
        let imageCellIdentifier = "ImageCell"

        //variables
        var imageForCell = UIImage()
        var testString = String()

        let object = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        var myText = object.objectForKey("postText") as? String
        println("MY TEXT -> \(myText)")
        var hasImage = object.objectForKey("hasImage") as? Bool
        let imageFromParse = object.objectForKey("postImage") as? PFFile
        //find if there is an image
         println("HASIMAGE IS->\(indexPath.row, hasImage)")

        //get image
        if hasImage == true
        {
            let imageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbieFeedImageTVCell
            println("RETURNED IMAGE->\(indexPath.row)")
            //set image for cell
            imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    if let myImageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:myImageData)
                        imageCell.cellImage!.image = image
                    }
                }
                }, progressBlock: { (percent: Int32) -> Void in
            })
            imageCell.cellText.text = "has image"
            return imageCell
        }
        else{
            let standardCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(standardCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbieFeedStandardTVCell
            println("RETURNED STANDARD->\(indexPath.row)")
            standardCell.cellText.text = "no image"
            return standardCell
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GuiSoySauce Welcome anytime :)